# Not able to do Spark-Submit or Spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark

On my Hadoop cluster whenever I do spark-submit or spark-shell or py-spark

it just goes on saying infinitely ....

```
16/01/15 16:27:50 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:51 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:52 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:53 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:54 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:55 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:56 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:57 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:58 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:27:59 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:28:00 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:28:01 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/15 16:28:02 INFO Client: Application report for 
application_1452870745977_0005 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

I waited for a very long time but this message just doesn't go away ... does anyone have an idea of what went wrong with the spark shell?

Comment: Ensure that enough resources (mem/cpu) are available in the cluster to be able to run your app

Comment: which version of spark you are using.?

Comment: i am using 1.3.0 on cloudera 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved. My admin told me that many hadoop nodes had run out of local disk space because of very large log files.

when the log files were trimmed and space was freed, then spark started working again.